# Liferay Notification: Add Generated password in notifcation

Tags: xml, notifications, liferay, workflow

Im trying to add generated password as notification to admin when user created a new account from login form

- **Question 1**: It is possible to add here the generated password as caption using Kaleo Workflow?

**Actual Screenshot**

[image: Liferay Notification]

**To like this:**
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me know which site you want to show the user's passwords to random administrators so that I make sure to never create an account there. Seriously: This is a big no-no and you shouldn't do it.

That being said: Can you do this? Yes. Will I tell you how to do this? No. It's the wrong solution to a wrong problem. This is a requirement that should be rejected violently IMHO.

Alternatively, if you need to tell the users their password, you might consider explicitly setting the password to a value that's well known (by the administrators) and make note of it this way. Liferay provides the option to update the user account by API, so you can easily write your custom implementation of the "set user password" operation. This should be even easier to include in your workflow of briefing new users.

Comment: Thank you for your response @Olaf Kock, do you have any suggestions where do i put the generated password to notification, just like from default when user create account from login form, after filled up the form it shows the generated password before login.

But my requirements is to notify admin account generated password just like i said. Thank you very much.

Comment: Sharing the password with *anyone* is the rewuirement that I suggest to reject. Why should anyone but the one who signs in be in possession of the password? An Administrator has enough power to reset the password, impersonate a user or do other similar things if they need.

Comment: I know what is your saying but its only for generated password from liferay, because in default liferay gives you a generated password after register (without password bcos of genpass) and when user use the generated password its automatically redirect to change password to personal password, the only reason why admin get the generated password at first, is to distribute the password by personal with identification details to users.

Thank you again @Olaf Kock

Comment: I think lets close this question thank you @Olaf Kock for your suggestion

Comment: see my additional alternative as a reply to your previous comment.